# How to move the colorbar in Folium?

Tags: folium

Does anyone know how to move the color bar in a Folium map?  It seems to be stuck at the top, but I would like to position it either vertically at the side or on the bottom of the map.  I can't see anything in the documentation about this, but there must be a solution...

[image]